# Searching and sorting in text files

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, text

I am fairly new to code and i have a problem in reading a text file. 
For my code i need to ask the user to type in a specific name code in order to proceed to the code. However, there are various name codes the user could use and i don't know how to make it so if you type either code in, you can proceed.

For example the text file looks like this

john123,x,x,x

susan233,x,x,x

conor,x,x,x

What i need to do is accept the name tag despite what one it is and be able to print it after. All the name tags are in one column.

```
file = open("paintingjobs.txt","r")

details = file.readlines()


for line in details:
    estimatenum = input ("Please enter the estimate number.")
    if estimatenum = line.split
```

This is my code so far, but i do not know what to do in terms of seeing if the name tag is valid to let the user proceed.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here. What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of output you expect, given a user input ? Anyway to check if the user input is present in a line of your text file, you can use "if estimatenum in line:".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a module called `pickle`. This is a Python 3.0 internal library. In Python 2.0, it is called: `cPickle`; everything else is the same in both.

Be warned that the way you're doing this is not a secure approach!

```
from pickle import dump

credentials = {
    'John': 1234,
    'James': 4321,
    'Julie': 6789
}


dump(credentials, open("credentials.p", "wb"))
```

This saves a file entitled `credentials.p`. You can the load this as follows:

```
from pickle import load

credentials = load(open("credentials.p", "rb"))

print(credentials)
```

Here are a couple of tests:

```
test_name = 'John'
test_code = 1234
```

This will amount to:

```
print('Test: ', credentials[test_name] == test_code)
```

which displays: `{'John': 1234, 'James': 4321, 'Julie': 6789}`

Displays: `Test:  True`

```
test_code = 2343
print('Test:', credentials[test_name] == test_code)
```

Displays: `Test: False`

Comment: Why bring `pickle` into this?

Comment: I'm afraid i cant use any imports really, i was hoping to find a solution without any imports. Thank you so much for the help though!

Comment: Simplistic approach. Easiest way to do what they want. Python's internal library. Opens data in the same structure as they were saved, that is, in this case, a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, without `pickle`. I'm assuming that your credentials are stored one per line. If not, you need to tell me how they are separated.

```
name = 'John'
code = '1234'

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    possible_match = [line.replace(name, '') for line in file if name in line]

authenticated = False

for item in possible_match:
    if code in tmp: # Or, e.g. int(code) == int(tmp) 
        authenticated = True
        break
```